# Clark-Ocone Formula

Tags: stochastic-processes

Why is the Clark-Ocone formula:
$F = E[F] + \int_0^T E[D_t F | F_t] dW_t$

important, besides its applications to finance. That is, can you give examples of any important pieces of pure theory where this formula is of central importance?

Comment: I am not so sure about theoretical results that are implied by Clark Ocone's Formula, I would say its main interest is to give a precise formulation to the martingale representation theorems that are available and which are "not " "constructive" results. In this regard it is an accomplishment of its own and it is not applicable to the only field of finance, the condition though is to be able to determine the Malliavin derivative ant is conditional expectation. Best regards